# I am not able to see icons in Document card although I am using class components

Tags: javascript, react-typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

Icons Which I am Using Are Of Fluent ui's and I am Following IconsProps For the css.
Example:

```js
const closeIcon: IIconProps = {
  iconName: 'ChromeClose',
  styles: {
    root: {
      color: 'white',
      padding: '18px 0px',
      fontSize: "15px"
    }
  }
};
```

I want to use `Icons` in `Documentcard` via Class Components